# Program crashes when trying to display an image using ImageView

Tags: android

Hi all
I am new to android and am having trouble doing something very simple- I would like to an an image to my xml file.  Heres the xml code in configure_screen.xml (I commented out some of the irrelevant stuff) :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/rings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/imageName"></ImageView> </LinearLayout>
```

Then, in my activity file, my onCreate() method only contains the line 
    setContentView(R.layout.configure_screen);

I added the image to the drawable-mdpi folder.  When I try to run it on the emulator it says "The application has stopped unexpectedly".  The same thing happens when I replace the "@drawable/imageName" with "@drawable/icon".

I'm sure its something simple that I am missing, does anyone know how to fix? I can add the LogCat information if anyone is interested.

Comment: Definitely add the LogCat. It'll make things much easier to diagnose.

Comment: add the logCat information plz , it will help as to figure out the problem

Comment: are you sure the device/emulator you are running this on has an mdpi screen? if you just put the image in the `drawable` folder does it work?

Comment: for one thing, it's better to stick to all-lowercase-and-underscores for resource names. So better `image_name` than `imageName` (of course that does not count for the `icon` test).

Comment: Putting the  image in 'drawable' does seem to make it work- but I thought (from Android Application Development for Dummies :) that you didn't need to do that, and should instead put different versions of the image in the different drawables folders.   Could someone explain how that works?

Comment: If you only have one image size it should go into the default drawable folder, else you should have appropriate sized images in low, med and high density folders. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add your image to a new folder "drawable" by creating as you have specified drawable in src for the image view(and not drawable-mdpi).
Try it......i did it and it worked well